# django - how can I clean variable data passed by an url?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

When I'm using a form I clean field data using Django forms but how do you clean variable data that's passed by an URL?

For example I have an URL like this: **http://mywebsite.com/tags/my-tag/** where **my-tag** is the variable that I'm passing to a function on my views.py.

I tried to use a Django form to clean the data but I'm getting en error saying "**'TagForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'**". 
I know **my-form** variable is reaching the **tags** function in the views.py since I'm able to show its content on a template so the problem is probably with the way I'm using the form.

**views.py**

```
def tags(request, my-tag):
    tagform = TagForm(request.GET)
    cleaned_dt = tagform.cleaned_data
    form_tag = cleaned_dt['tag']
```

**forms.py**

```
class TagForm(forms.Form):
    tag = forms.CharField()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Practically what I need is a way of cleaning variable data passed from an URL. You can ignore my example if there is some other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cleaned_data` dictionary attribute appears after you call `is_valid` method on your form.

```
def tags(request, my-tag):
    tagform = TagForm(request.GET)
    if tagform.is_valid():
        cleaned_dt = tagform.cleaned_data
        form_tag = cleaned_dt['tag']
    return render(request, "may_template.html", {"form":tagform})
```

Comment: Adding if tagform.is_valid(): solved the "TagForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'" error. Now I still need to figure out how to clean that variable passed from the url.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a TagForm with a request object, but you're not giving the TagForm the value of `my-tag` anywhere that I can see.

The `/my-tag/` section of the URL isn't a request parameter. It's part of the url, and presumably passed to the view function as `my-tag` (you might want to rename it `my_tag` to be more Pythonic).

*Edit*

You can simple create a dict object to initialize to Form object instead of request.GET. [An example is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms).

```
data = {'tag': my_tag,
    'anotherIfNecessary': 'Hi there'}

tagform = TagForm(data)
```

Basically, the dictionary used to populate a form object must contain a mapping of form field names to the value you wish to set it at.

In this case, you have a form field name of "tag" and want to set it to `my-tag` (are you sure you don't get a syntax error with the dash in the variable name? I do...). I've corrected my example.

Comment: I think you are right about not passing the my-tag variable to the form. Now the question is how do I pass it to the form?

Comment: Evan, I tried your code and added also form_tag = cleaned_dt['my_tag'] below it as I would with a regular form but there is nothing passed to the "form_tag" variable. 
To test that I added {{form_tag}} on a template and there is nothing displayed.